# Playing local recorded video

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I just want to record a video, copy it to local storage and be able to replay it. I have tried numerous different solutions. It works fine when debugging on an actual device from VS but as soon as the app is transferred to Apple I only get the red rectangle without content.

XAML:

```
<xct:MediaElement
  BackgroundColor="red"
  x:Name="mediaElement"
  Source="{Binding Video}" 
  ShowsPlaybackControls="True"
  HeightRequest="400"
  HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
```

MVVM:

```
public async void MoveVideo(FileResult fileResult)
{
  var documentsFolder = GetVideoFolderPath();
  var newFile = Path.Combine(documentsFolder, fileResult.FileName);
  using (var stream = await fileResult.OpenReadAsync())
  using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
    await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

  var ex = System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(documentsFolder, fileResult.FileName));        // just to validate - returns true
}

public string GetVideoFolderPath()
{
  var documentsFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
  return documentsFolder;
}

private void CheckVideo() {
  var documentsFolder = _videoService.GetVideoFolderPath();
  var pathAndFile = Path.Combine(documentsFolder, LocalFilePath);
  var b = new System.Uri(pathAndFile).AbsolutePath;
  if(File.Exists(pathAndFile)) 
  {
    Video = MediaSource.FromFile(b);
  }
}
```

Please note that it works and shows the video when debugging from VS. How can I ensure the playback?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried deploying directly to your device using the Release profile?  Have you tried adding any exception handling, logging, or crash reporting to the app?

Comment: It does not crash, it just does not show the video. The File.Exists returns true in both copy and view. I have released it to device through both TestFlight and Ad Hoc. In both cases the video does not show. If debugging through VS on the same device it works.

Comment: That does not answer any of the questions I asked.   `File.Exists` just tells that some file with that name exists, not that it is the right size or contains the right content.

Comment: Alright, sorry. I now tried to run it directly on the release profile, and it is the same problem. No video. I have looked through crash logs and trailed the console logs. I cant find anything that points me in any direction. Can I add something directly to the media element? Can I try other kinds of logging?